# Show "total contributions" from all results in data processor or search kit?

Tags: searchkit, data-processor

I've created a few contribution reports using data processor / search kits / afforms for my colleagues.  They work great as my colleagues can quickly see the contributions as well as performing actions on them (sending email, printing acknowledgement letters, etc.).  However, I'm unable to find a way to show the "total contributions" aggregated from all or the filtered results.  My current workaround is to export them into excel to add them up or to run a similar contribution reports, but I wonder if there is a way to show the total contribution directly in data processor output / search kit / afforms?  Any advice is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: the way we have achieved this in the past (i suspect SearchKit offers new options) is to use the Summary Fields extension

Comment: Are you looking for something like a "Grand Total" line at the bottom?

Comment: Hi @Coleman,
Yes, I'm looking for a way to show the Grand Total.  I've tried the summary fields, but I'm unable to (or I haven't figured out a way to) show the grand total through the summary fields.  Any guidance is appreciated.

PS~ I'm able to pull regular / extended reports to show the grant total, but my colleague really like the SearchKit / Data Process interface, where they can perform actions on the records (primarily printing / emailing receipts and sending other email correspondence).

Comment: I expect that feature will be coming soon from SearchKit. There's been new sponsorship.

Answer (score 2):

As of this writing SearchKit doesn't have the ability to do a "grand total" style row. You could create one search display that displays each row, and a second search display which shows aggregated totals using GROUP BY, but it can't currently be done within the same search display table.

However, SearchKit is still in development and new features are being sponsored and added all the time. Hop on https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/search-improvements if you'd like to chip in to sponsor a feature like this!

Comment: just to clarify, are you suggesting to add multiple search displays within a single afform? Or have 2 identical queries and each has a display with different GROUP BY settings? I have done the latter option but didn't know if the first was even possible.

Comment: Yes you can now add > 1 search display per afform, as of CiviCRM 5.49 (current beta)

Answer (score 1):

Update - the 'Total' feature has been added.

Tick the 'Show totals in footer' option:

[image]

then configure the footer for each column:

[image]

Result:

[image]