# Needing a way to sum a column in a searchkit report

Tags: reports, searchkit, formbuilder

We have several reports that involve quantities (resources purchased, donations, participant attendance, etc) and we would like to be able to sum all values in a column. I haven't found a quick way to do this for a SearchKit report. Our current method usually involves an export and then manipulating the data in Excel. We are trying to find ways to keep our users in Civi rather than working in spreadsheets.

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear: you want this break-down as well as a total?  If so, see https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/41425/225

Comment: @Aidan, thanks for the link. That's exactly what I'm looking for. I will keep an eye out for this feature to be added. It is more of a "wish list" item for us so it's not super pressing. Thanks again.